# How to re-calculate the x,y values of a line as per different screen size/resolution in OpenGL?

Tags: c#, opengl

Am getting x,y values as large values, so the line can't be drawn since the coordinates lie down beyond the respective window coordinates. how to re-calculate the x,y values as per different screen size/resolution in OpenGL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenGL has no mechanism for getting "x,y values of a line".

Comment: What I want to know is, how to re-size x,y values according to my screen size/resolution(suppose I have large values for x,y).

Answer (score 0):

In openGL this is done using what's called a "projection matrix". This will define how your "world coordinates" map to your screen.

If you're still using the fixed-function pipeline of "old" OpenGL, then this done by selecting it " glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); " then applying operations on it do to the mapping you want ( glLoadIdentity, glScale, glRotate, glTranslate, glOrtho, .... )

If you're using shaders, then it's up to you to actually use uniforms to setup that matrix and apply it to all your vertex coordinates in your vertex shader.

See https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/05/22/opengl-101-matrices-projection-view-model/